How does current in the cable shield affect the signal in the wires within
The common anecdotal explanation for why the screen of signal cables should only be grounded at one end is to avoid ground loops. Magnetic fields through ground loops generate current in the loop. Fine, but how would this current affect the signal in the wires within the screen?
Will not the current through the screen create a circular magnetic field around the screen? How can this field induce any current in the wires within, assuming symmetry, twisted wires or not? Will not this circular magnetic field act to induce current in the wires equally, thus cancelling out the effect?
Looking for a first principles explanation of the effect.

Current isn't induced; voltage is induced by the rate of change of current (the rate of change of flux).

Right, if an outside magnetic field can't get into the wires, it doesn't affect them.
The question is: when is a shield a shield -- or not?
When a magnetic field penetrates a conductive layer, that's equivalent to saying, induced current and conductivity is insufficient to stop the magnetic field.  In other words, frequency is below the skin effect cutoff, and the conductor looks like just another resistive wire in the cable -- its exact positioning (beside or around other conductors) in the cable isn't so important anymore.
For frequency well above the skin effect cutoff, the shield is effective, separating currents into interior (signal) and exterior (common mode) currents independently.  If the end connectors maintain this separation of currents, CMRR is high and signal quality is preserved -- whatever the relation of signals within happens to be (normal mode signal(s) or differential).
For a truly first-principles explanation, you'll have to research the field solution under which skin effect arises; I haven't worked with fields in quite a while so can't give an accurate run-through of it.  But also, perhaps this is sufficient connection to be convincing.

The "ground at one end" tip is old advice, very old; and bad advice.  It is best forgotten, and a note such as this, attached to every instance of it, at every opportunity available.
The principle is actually effective, but only in two scenarios:

Electric fields, at low frequencies and high (system) impedances.
The shield (connected or floating, doesn't matter) blocks inhomogeneous EM fields from coupling between wires within the cable.

For (1), low frequencies are much smaller than than a wavelength in the transmission line.  Impedances is relative to characteristic impedance; typically 100s of ohms, so that the cable has capacitive effect in circuit.
For (2), it's rare that this is ever a problem: EM fields are usually distant enough that a twisted pair suffices to average it out along the length of the cable.  Conversely, a very local field, less than the length between twists let's say, just doesn't have much area over which to couple -- you'd have to have a periodic source that just happens to line up with the twist, and that's very rare indeed.  (Well, that or accidental: it's no accident that multi-twisted-pair cables are normally made with unequal twist rates between the pairs!)  Or, it's at high enough frequency where that small coupling area is sufficient, but such frequencies (100s MHz, GHz) are rarely if ever transmitted over twisted pair.[1]
Since (1) is the more important case, we can identify historic relevance.  Back in the vacuum tube days, typical (grid or plate) circuit impedances were a couple kΩ minimum, and thus capacitive coupling is dominant.  Cables were typically short (≪1m in most chassis wiring; up to perhaps 10s m in studio applications), frequencies low (audio); and signal levels may be high, making ground loop voltage less significant (though even back then, a couple volts RMS/peak was typically it).  Grounded consumer equipment is also a relatively new thing, though I don't know too much about contemporary studio equipment (but, differential signaling has been in common use there anyway).
The advice is between neutral and actively harmful in all other cases.  In particular, it is especially harmful in modern high-speed digital communications buses, like USB or HDMI, which require a common-ground reference plane from transmitter, through connectors and cable, to the receiver.
As mentioned, it does break the ground loop of a galvanic circuit, but it doesn't make the situation better: instead, it guarantees that, whatever ground loop voltage exists between devices, is imposed precisely in series with the signal(s), ensuring maximum voltage interference.  Whether that's specifically a problem, depends on the equipment, but pretty clearly when it's unipolar signals like audio via RCA cable, breaking the shield means no ground reference at all.  When the signal is differential, the ground loop is already a solved problem and there is no justification for breaking the shield.
And yes, even back then, people got in trouble for following this advice!  A radio amplifier might be built with this applied, but then the resonant stub created by the one-end-shorted cable shield caused the connected amplifying stage to oscillate at some 100s MHz.  "Grid stopper" resistors were a common sight, without understanding or analysis of when and why they are needed -- easier to install them generally, than to try and understand and fix whatever VHF-UHF nightmare of a network your loose wiring and tuned coils have created.  They were just simpler days back then, and simple solutions sufficed.
The same thing of course happens in audio amps, where tubes of high gm and modest feedback capacitance can create tuned-grid oscillators in the same environment.
[1] Yes, Ethernet of course -- but keep in mind, even 1000BASE-T tops out at 125Mbaud.  Even the 2.5, 5 and 10G series top out at 800Mbaud; bandwidth is improved as much by using more complex line coding.  Which does mean more sensitivity to signal quality -- there is a certain asymptotic tradeoff between degree of interference, or line imbalance or mismatch, and the (electrical) length of that imbalance, i.e. how much length of cable has been interfered with.

Single-end grounds do not improve the ingress of EMI from magnetic fields unless the field is uniform at both ends. However, source-only ground shields on STP cable or shielded twinax may improve EMI from conducted currents created by ground loops on low frequencies without transmission line effects. When unbalanced impedance inputs see a common-mode current, a differential voltage is created.
For example, on CATV coaxial grounds are critical and distributed. Poor grounds create RF ingress problems just as above. I measured this on residential CATV distribution lines near train tracks correlated with radiated EMI whenever a train passed, due to the brushed DC motors. Circa 1982.
Examples of where shields are grounded at both ends are when the bandwidth of digital signals is UHF ( >300 MHz or when it is likely that the cable length will exceed 1/10th of a wavelength.  This is a fundamental criterion for choosing both ends grounded.  Differential signals even at 1GHz speeds are preferred to use UTP or unshielded twisted pairs and use Baluns and isolation transformers in the PHY or RJ-45 jack to improve the CMRR noise of interference. If you examine the ethernet Phy's you may note an AC cap to ground that blocks low-frequency noise from conducting.  Even HDMI signals may use SMD baluns on boards and use grounds at both ends.
The assumptions for shields are not always clear and there are different opinions. If you don't use baseband near DC, UTP may be superior.  (e.g. biphase encoding if you use Baluns.)
https://www.cablinginstall.com/connectivity/rj45-utp-shielded/article/16469421/shielded-and-unshielded-twisted-pair-cable-revisited

You're using "EMI" = Electro-Magnetic Immunity, I think? -- An unconventional definition, but the first paragraph doesn't seem to read correctly for "-Interference" as the direction is unstated (susceptibility or emissions): whereas, breaking the ground almost certainly increases emissions.

EMI/EMC always defines both ingress and egress.     1st para. edit for clarity.

The problem of ground loop currents is not that they induce voltages into the signal but that the signal no longer has a working reference.
The voltage in an open loop corresponds to the magnetic flux changes passing through it which is the same for signal and shield, meaning that as long as you keep them in parallel, you will not notice any difference.  The moment you close the loop, this accumulated voltage has to go somewhere.
If the shield and all connectors have zero resistance, the ground loop will carry anough current to nullify the flux changes passing through the loop.  This current passes very close to the signal.  A perfectly straight perfectly homogenous coaxial cable will not have shield currents induce voltages in the core.
But coaxial cables are not perfectly straight and homogenous.  For external fields and currents, that is a good approximation.  But when we are effectively collecting the effects of external fields and placing them right next to the signal, any imperfections get magnified by a whole lot.
Additionally, the "zero resistance" model is not likely to hold true, so the loop voltage is not offset completely by the loop current's magnetic field but is also offset by resistive voltages along the wires and contact points, and those resistive voltages are not paralleled in the signal that doesn't have similar currents.
